# Does polynomial interpolation using Chebyshev nodes always convege?

Tags: numerical-methods

On my lecture nodes, it says "Polynomial interpolation on Chebyshev nodes using the barycenteric form is extremely robust". Does that mean it always converges?

Here, "robustness" refers to "the effect of round-off error, in particular as the number of data points n increases".

Comment: See the  3 theorems here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation#Convergence_properties